# multiple date format to change specifc format

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

There are two date columns i want to calculate day differences or year differences. However, there are multiple date formats for each value.

For example, I have two columns `Date1` & `Date2`

```
Date1
01/90 (MM/YY)
1991 (YYYY)
11/11/1992 (dd/MM/yyyy)
```

`Date2` also has multiple formats as `Date1`

How can I calculate differences between those two dates which are in multiple date format?

Is it efficient way to change all those multiple formats int specif format first and calculate differences?

Or is there a way to calculate date differences without change the format into specific format?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at SimpleDateFormat and Calendar

Comment: What data types are your columns, `VARCHAR()`?

Comment: data types are nvarchar